# Compiling and running Java app

Tags: java, classpath

#### **The problem:**

I can't get my java app to run after compiling. My guess is there's something wrong my classpaths.

Just to clear things up I have used an IDE, Eclipse, and I originally used that to compile and run my application. It ran perfectly, but now I need to run it strictly through the terminal/command line. The reason is that I follow a guideline that if it cant be run on the command line then it doesn't exist. (Helps me really get to know my applications)

Anyway here's the environment

#### **OS**

32bit Linux AWS distro (Based off of CentOS)

#### **Installed software**

- yum install subversion*
- yum install java*

#### **The Application structure**

- staff/src/com/staffS3/Helpers/Constants.java
- staff/src/net/UploadFile.java

#### **Classpaths**

- export CLASSPATH="/home/ec2-user/staff/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.2.1.jar:."
- export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jre/"

#### **Compiling**

```
javac /home/ec2-user/staff/src/com/staffS3/Helpers/Constants.java /home/ec2-user/staff/src/net/UploadFile.java
```

Compiles correctly (Atleast without any errors)

#### **To run it**

```
java UploadFile
```

#### **Error**

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: UploadFile (wrong name: net/UploadFile)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    Could not find the main class: UploadFile. Program will exit.
```

Been at this for a while. Hopefully someone will notice that little(or huge) thing I'm missing :).

Thanks in advance

Comment: whats your working directory when you run 'java UploadFile'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To run it
>
> ```
> java UploadFile
> ```

You musn't `cd` into the `src/net` directory. Just go to `src` and do

```
java net.UploadFile
```

You need to stand in a directory such that `java` can find the file `net/UploadFile.class`.

The *"Wrong Name*" error message (and it's cause) is described well [here](http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html).

---

Note also that setting the classpath through `-cp` is the preferred way. I.e., try

```
java -cp .:/home/ec2-user/staff/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.2.1.jar net.UploadFile
```

---

Finally, mixing .java files and .class files is a bad idea. Use the `-d` switch when running `javac` to specify a destination directory for the class files. Call the directory `bin` or `build`.

Comment: Wow talk about fast responses. It's almost like calling a coding support hotline or something. Pretty sure you fixed the problem! I just need to go hunt down some apache jars, but other than that it seems like my error is fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially it looks like you're trying to run it using the base name, not including the package.

Try running it from the "src" folder, and running `java net.UploadFile`

Comment: Yup that was the problem. Thanks a lot!